# CSS hide style of sibling for element with specific ID

Tags: css

I am trying to hide sibling 1 and 2 that comes after an element with a specific ID I thought the code would look something like:

```
div[id*="pop_up"] + class{
  display: none !important; 
}
```

However, this does not seem to work, I am unsure how exactly I would use the sibling combination in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below is what you want.

```css
div#pop_up + *,
div#pop_up + * + * {
  display: none; !important; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pop_up"> Pop Up </div>
<h1> sibling 1</h1>
<p> sibling 2</p>
<div> sibling 3</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I want! Is there anyway to just remove all the siblings?

Comment: ```div#pop_up * {
        display: none; !important
    }```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector will only hide the first sibling having the specified class. If you want to remove the first and second sibling, you'll need something like the following:

```css
div[id*="pop_up"] + .hide-me, 
div[id*="pop_up"] + .hide-me + .hide-me {
  display: none !important; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pop_up1"></div>

<p class="hide-me">Hide me!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me!</p>
```

Alternatively, you can use the General Sibling Selector, but that will cause **all** siblings with the specified class to be hidden. For example:

```css
div[id*="pop_up"] ~ .hide-me {
  display: none !important; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pop_up1"></div>

<p class="hide-me">Hide me!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me!</p>
```

If you don't want to add selectors *ad infinitum* as shown in the first snippet, you can combine the `~` selector with `nth-child` as follows:

```css
div[id*="pop_up"] ~ .hide-me:nth-child(-n+3) {
   display: none !important; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pop_up1"></div>

<p class="hide-me">Hide me 1!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me 2!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me 3!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me 4!</p>
<p class="hide-me">Hide me 5!</p>
```

Comment: This is awesome, is there a way where I can just hide all the siblings irrespective of what their class is?